# Pandas Series: Extract text between parenthesis including them

Tags: python, series, text-extraction

How can I include the parenthesis when I extract text from a pandas series?

```
my_series.str.extract('\((.*)\)')
```

Comment: What have you tried? What doesn't work? And what is your data looking like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the parenthesis captured inside the capture group, you need to put the escaped parenthesis inside the group like this :

```
my_series.str.extract('(\(.*\))')
```

Answer (score 0):

`my_series.str.extract('((.*))')` - removing the escape character / retrieves all the content (and not a partial match if that is what is required).
`my_series.str.extract('((\)))')`  - retrieves only the )

Comment: Hi Geetha, welcome to Stack Overflow! Consider improving your answer by formatting code as code using ` on either side of the code text. Consider also showing an example of the difference in outputs between the two extractions.

Comment: Can you try a different function ie findall
`my_series = pd.Series(['(Text12num$bers)', 'Jus(t)Text'])
new_series = my_series.str.findall(r'[a-zA-Z\(\)]+')`

**Result**
0    [(Text, num, bers)]
1           [Jus(t)Text]


if there are characters that are removed, the return element is an array containing more than one element. You can use the join function 

to join them
`my_series.str.findall(r'[a-zA-Z\(\)]+').str.join("")`
**Result**
0    (Textnumbers)
1       Jus(t)Text